# GitLab CI python subprocess.Popen permission denied

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running a GitLab-CI job which runs a python script which starts a `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

```
def main():
  proc = subprocess.Popen("./../binary_file --args value", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is that I'm getting

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './../binary_file'

Ok. Maybe I forgot to set appropriate permissions?

```
$ chmod +x ./binary_file
$ ls -l ./binary_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30335023 Apr  1 14:16 ./binary_file
$ whoami
root
```

Well I'm not.

So what could be the reason of such behavior?

The `script` part of a `gitlab-ci` job

```
script:
    - chmod +x ./binary_file
    - ls -l ./binary_file
    - whoami
    - pipenv run python ./scripts/run_tests.py
```

Comment: based on the code that you provided, I see the different paths to the file in the script and the python file. Make sure that the path is correct. Try using `os.getcwd()`. The next possible issue could be is the folder that contains the file might have stricter restrictions. Try 'ls -ld' to see the folder permissions

Comment: @RAI thx for your suggestion. `ls -ld` - OK no restrictions

Comment: another possible issue could be that you are executing this script via python script which might have a different user/permissions

Comment: @RAI thx `I see the different paths to the file in the script and the python file` it was the case! You can add an answer to my question I will accept and vote!

Comment: I would double check the path is correct. `print(pathlib.Path('./../binary_file').absolute())`

Comment: @sytech yes, it was the case! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the code that you provided, I see the different paths to the file in the script and the python file. Make sure that the path is correct. Try using `os.getcwd()`.